# remove JTextArea from tab list WindowBuilderPro

Tags: windowbuilder

I have 3 textFields, 3 textAreas and 2 buttons on a form created using WindowBuilderPro. When I press tab I want to tab through these items but exclude the textAreas from being reachable. In VS for C#, there's an attribute for each item which you just uncheck if you want to remove it from the tab list, but I can't see anyhing like this in WBP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: it's under tab order